# Google Workspaceに連携するGCPプロジェクト/組織を削除したい

Tags: google-workspace, google-cloud-platform

Google Workspace(GW)を統合するため、不要になったGWを削除したいと考えています。

**発生している問題**

1. GWの削除操作をした場合、GCPにアクティブなプロジェクトが存在するので削除できない旨が表示される
   [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
2. GCPでプロジェクトを削除するも、1で示した状態は変わらずGWの削除ができない
   [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]
3. GCPで組織を削除すれば、GWで削除操作できるか試みたがGCP側で組織の削除操作ができない。[組織の管理者]をロールとして設定しても、削除の項目が表示されない
   [image: 画像の説明をここに入力]